# Look for a max value in an Excel table, starting from left

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup

I have a table in Excel, let say in the following format:

```
_| A | B | C 
1| 0 | 5 | 11
2| 0 | 6 | 7
3| 0 | 7 | 3
```

I need to start search for a max value in A, if all 0 then pass to the next column B and return 7. 
Or if B contains all 0 then pass to C and return 11.
I tried to play with vlookup, "index match match" and max combination, but failed to deliver. No VBA please.
Is it a doable task?

Comment: What is the first column' the letter?

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
=IF(MAX(A1:A3)=0,IF(MAX(B1:B3)=0,MAX(C1:C3),MAX(B1:B3)),MAX(A1:A3))
```